# UX.SE Site Doesn't Display Well In Network Chat Rooms

Tags: feature-request, design

[image: UX.SE onebox is white text on a light background.]
[image]

I'm referring to the 'onebox' that occurs when you post the URL of a stackexchange site into one of the chatrooms on the network.  As most of these rooms have a light background, the UX onebox is nearly impossible to read.

Can we get this modified somehow?

Comment: Upon further inspection and confirmation from Jin, apparently these are just pulled straight from the site's logo image, which really just is that color.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.